# 2006 Sedona stopped running while driving, will not start now

Tags: engine, kia, sedona

The van cranks but will not start now. Checked for spark and fuel, all is good.

Below is the scan results I got. This scan was taken after several tries and checking the cam and crank sensors.

```
Make: Kia  
Model: Sedona 3.8L  
Year: 2006 
VIN: KNDMB233366060650  
MIL: Off
```

### Diagnostic Trouble Codes

**`Generic Powertrain`**

```
P2106 Lime Home Mode - Force Limited Power      
P1295 Limp Home Mode - Power Management      
P2422 Evaporative Emission System Vent Valve Stuck Close      
P0300 Random/Multiple Cylinder Misfire Detected       
P0302 Cylinder 2 Misfire Detected       
P0304 Cylinder 4 Misfire Detected       
P0452 Evaporative Emission Control System Pressure Sensor Low Input      
P161b Unknown Trouble Code Description      
P0018 Crankshaft Position - Camshaft Position Correlation - Bank 2 Sensor A
```

**`Freeze Frame for DTC P0300`**

```
Fuel System Status Bank One Closed Loop  
Fuel System Status Bank Two Not Reported  
Calculated Load 27 %  
Coolant Temperature 93 F  
Short Term Fuel Trim Bank One 17.94 %  
Long Term Fuel Trim Bank One 0.00 % 
Short Term Fuel Trim Bank Two 18.72 %  
Long Term Fuel Trim Bank Two 0.00 %  
Intake Manifold Absolute Pressure 20.9 in.hg  
Engine RPM 2340 r/min  
Vehicle Speed 0 MPH  
Ignition Timing Advance for #1 19.0 deg  
Intake Air Temperature 82 F  
Air Flow Rate From Mass Air Flow Sensor 3.15 lb/min  
Absolute Throttle Position 22 %  
B1S1 O2 Sensor Output Voltage 0.000 V  
B1S2 O2 Sensor Output Voltage 1.275 V  
B2S1 O2 Sensor Output Voltage 0.000 V  
B2S2 O2 Sensor Output Voltage 1.275 V
```

**`Enhanced Powertrain`**

```
P2106 Lime Home Mode - Force Limited Power  
B3b12 Unknown Trouble Code Description  
U20bb Unknown Trouble Code Description  
P22e0 Unknown Trouble Code Description  
P0300 Random/Multiple Cylinder Misfire Detected   
B3f04 Unknown Trouble Code Description  
B2099 Unknown Trouble Code Description
```

**`Automatic Transmission`**

```
P2106 Lime Home Mode - Force Limited Power  
B3b12 Unknown Trouble Code Description  
U20bb Unknown Trouble Code Description  
P22e0 Unknown Trouble Code Description  
P0300 Random/Multiple Cylinder Misfire Detected  
B3f04 Unknown Trouble Code Description  
B2099 Unknown Trouble Code Description
```

**`SRS-Airbag`**

```
B2500 Warning Lamp Fault Short To Battery Or Bulb Short
```

**`Weight Control System (WCS)`**

```
No response from module
```

**`ABS / TCS / ESP`**

```
No response from module
```

**`BCM`**

```
B1102 Battery Voltage Too Low  
B1602 CAN Line Error  
B1606 CAN Time-Out ADM
```

**`Air Conditioning`**

```
No response from module
```

**`Powertail Gate`**

```
No response from module
```

**`Power Sliding Door LH`**

```
No response from module
```

**`Power Sliding Door RH`**

```
No response from module
```

**`TPMS`**

```
No diagnostic codes retrieved
```

Comment: Wow! That's a list of trouble codes! The one which has me worried is P0018. I don't know *exactly* what it means, but it sure sounds like the timing belt has slipped and the engine is now out of time.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 it may be but i'd suspect a bad oil control valve or pressure issue first. Maybe the OP can do a cmp/ckp correlation test with both oc valves unplugged to confirm.

Comment: @Ben - I'd suspect you may be right. Read through some of the issues involved with the code. Seems to focus on a cam phaser issue pulling a cam out of time. The part which bugs me is the engine won't run at all, which seems to be beyond the difference a cam phaser could provide. Seems like the OP has a pretty good diagnostic tool to be able to pull out for all the different modules on the CANBus, so might have the ability to do what you're asking.

Comment: According to the interwebs, the 2006 Sedona has a timing chain, not belt.

Comment: By fuel do you mean injector pulse or fuel pressure?

Comment: I checked fuel ppresse

Comment: I checked for fuel pressure but do not have gauge to test ti.  by adding gas into the intake tube I could get it to run, but it did not run strong as I think it should when dumping gas into it.

Comment: is there marks to check the cam timing?

Comment: The tool used to read the trouble codes is a laptop running AutoEnginuty, with the KIA enhanced upgrade.

Comment: I pulled the front (right) valve cover and saw that both rimming chains were on, and seamed to be tensioned.

Comment: I noticed that one of those codes was battery voltage low and short to ground. I've seen battery problems and battery ground problems cause all sorts of screwy and performance issues. For instance poor battery performance can cause your fuel pump to not work at full power. Also check your vacuum presure because that can mess with a whole bunch of timing related stuff. The real thing to find out is the actual failure order rather than the list of codes because that will tell you what set the cascade off.

Comment: I have checked the battery, it seams to be good.  this scan was taken after several tries ti start, so the battery may have been challenged at the time.  the Limp home code confuses me, as when i was driving it i felt a supstanchil loss of power and found a safe place to stop and turn off the van.  No start after that.

Comment: put a noid light or scope one of the injectors to check for injector pulse. does the car have an electronic throttle body? that would explain the limp mode codes. Some of the codes you posted are garbage and you need to recheck the codes with another scanner.

Comment: I will need to get a noid light. As for the other codes, with the enhanced KIA software, I can read all the trouble codes.  I am foundering if the system is shutting it self down because of some other failure

Comment: With so many electrical issues, I wonder if there's a missing/blown fuse or a wiring harness problem.

Answer (score 2):

Had Dodge shadow do same thing too many codes . I took it to Corbin KY pickards automotive technician and had broke ground in working harness to computer. The technician fixed it in about 20 minutes no more problems after that.dont no if it's what's wrong but from all your codes I'd say good possibility. Good luck

Comment: I also got 2007 Nissan frontier tear kept reading codes like that turned out crankshaft sensor kept getting worse and then went out .that truck would not start. Took it to shop had it put on diagnosist machine sensor had went to ground shut fire off went to ground according to Nissan technician.

Answer (score 1):

Check the fuse for ENG and see if its blown. This happened to me and that's what the problem was until now. It keeps blowing and now my radio or nothing works and it cranks but wont start. I also have a 2006 Kia Sedona.

Answer (score 0):

I'm with /u/Hari Ganti.

It's too many codes to happen all at once, which points to an electrical issue.

I'd make sure you have clean power. Make sure all the grounds are clean and secure. Make sure nothing is shorted etc. I'd check the harness to the PCM.  Sounds like a possible rodent issue.